# Can you manipulate a number within a string with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

I have some strings like so:

```
<p>It will vary from 100g to 200g</p>
<p>2lbs of meat</p>
<p>3 piles of timber</p>
```

etc etc

I would like to increment/decrement all numbers in each string.
Any pointers?

---

**Additional notes:**

1. No, the number can be anywhere in the string.
2. @cookie_monster I would like to see if it's possible without the usual operations.

Comment: Is the number always at the beginning?

Comment: You'd extract the numeric value from the text, convert it to a number, manipulate it, then concatenate it back in. Will the number always be at the start? Will there every be more than one? Where do the strings come from? Are they in the DOM?

Comment: How about some of your HTML so we can push you in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Bradley, I have updated the post.

Comment: What are the "usual operations"?

Comment: @Felix Kling "You'd extract the numeric value from the text, convert it to a number, manipulate it, then concatenate it back in. Will the number always be at the start? Will there every be more than one?"

Comment: Your updated question shows HTML, so if the numbers are in the DOM, I'd really suggest wrapping them in `<span>` elements and targeting them directly. That is if you control the markup.

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution would be to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), for example:

```
"100g".replace(/\d+/g, function(n) { return +n + 1; }); // 101g
```

Explanation:

- The pattern `\d+` matches any sequence of one or more digits in a string.

  - This pattern limits you to integers only; if you tried this with `"3.5"` it would consider this to be two separate integers and the result would be `"4.6"`.
  - If this is a problem, use a pattern like `(\d+\.)?\d+` instead.
- The global flag (`g`) on the pattern means that this will replace all digit sequences in the string.

  - Remove this if you only want to replace the first instance.
- The function accepts the substring that was matched (in this case `"100"`) then converts it to a number (`+n`), adds 1, and returns the result. This result is converted back to a string, and replaces whatever was matched by the pattern.

To do this within an HTML element using jQuery, you could simply use something like this:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var e = $(this);
    e.text(e.text().replace(/\d+/g, function(n) { return +n + 1; }));
});
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. And for sniping me, for a change XD

Comment: you'll want to do `parseInt()` on the found value because JS likes to think things are strings unless you specify it

Comment: @Derek - note the `+`

Comment: @derek: the unary plus operator makes more sense here.

Comment: @adeneo: I imagine he's talking about hexadecimal syntax.

Comment: im ashamed to say i never even knew that unary `+` operator existed, and i've been doing JS programming for years! wow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to match numbers in the string, and a callback function to parse the number and alter it.

Example:

```
var s = "There are 4 lights.";

s = s.replace(/\d+/g, function(m){
    return parseInt(m, 10) + 1;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6YJQx/

To do this on several elements, you can use the `text` method with a callback:

```
$('p').text(function(i, s){
    return s.replace(/\d+/g, function(m){
        return parseInt(m, 10) + 1;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6YJQx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but to do it you need give numbers in spans. `<span> 100g </span>`.
Then, with jQuery .text, you can increment, decrement etc. the number.

Comment: You mean `<span>100</span>g`. Also the text inside the element is still text, you need to parse it to a number to do arithmetic operations on it.