# Increment String number javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry for this noob question but I'm really not good with javascript. I have list of String which has number at the end:

1. Test-001
2. Test-002
3. Test-003

I want to increment the numbers at the end of the String.

What I tried so far:

```
var test = 'Test-001';
var lastNum = test.split('-');

console.log( lastNum[1] + 1 ); // result: 0011
console.log( Number( lastNum[1] ) + 1 ) // result: 2
```

What I want to do is to produce results ( Test-001 up to Test-999 ).

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you manipulate a number within a string with Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137015/can-you-manipulate-a-number-within-a-string-with-jquery)

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you trying to do this **http://jsfiddle.net/Bws68/**

Comment: @p.s.w.g the title said jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close .... but try this on:

```
var test = 'Test-001';
var pieces = test.split('-');
var prefix = pieces[0];
var lastNum = pieces[1];
// lastNum is now a string -- lets turn it into a number. 
// (On older browsers, the radix 10 is essential -- otherwise it
// will try to parse the number as octal due to the leading zero.
// the radix is always safe to use and avoids any confusion.)

lastNum = parseInt(lastNum, 10);
// lastNum = +lastNum is also a valid option.

// Now, lets increment lastNum
lastNum++;

// Now, lets re-add the leading zeros
lastNum = ("0000" + lastNum).substr(-3);
```

Comment: `parseInt()` will not work because it needs to begin with a number. Your `lastNum` is `NaN`.

Comment: @RUJordan  Oops.. Fixed -- Thanks.  Ran that through my console and it worked properly now.

Comment: This is not valid if the lastNum is `Test-010` right?

Comment: @newbie -- Copy the code and run it in your own browser's console.  If you set `test` to `"Test-010"` then `lastNum` will correctly equal `011` at the end.

Comment: `("0000" + code).substr(-3)` can you explain the logic of this a bit? How come its result is still right even I the input is `Test-010`?

Comment: `"0000" + "013"` == "0000013"`.  The substr(-3) takes the last three characters from that, which will be `013`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
  var test = 'Test-001';
        var lastNum = test.split('-');
        var result=parseInt(lastNum[1]) + 1;
        console.log(parseInt(result, 10) < 100 ? ((parseInt(result, 10) < 10 ? ("00" + result) : ("0" + result))) : result);

        test = 'Test-009';
        lastNum = test.split('-');
        result = parseInt(lastNum[1]) + 1;
        console.log(parseInt(result, 10) < 100 ? ((parseInt(result, 10) < 10 ? ("00" + result) : ("0" + result))) : result);

        test = 'Test-099';
        lastNum = test.split('-');
        result = parseInt(lastNum[1]) + 1;
        console.log(parseInt(result, 10) < 100 ? ((parseInt(result, 10) < 10 ? ("00" + result) : ("0" + result))) : result);
```

This will help you.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but @jeremy's answer is much more simple.